# Rails Update with ActiveRecord Collection or Array causing ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

We are setting role assignments(project_id, role_id) for user access to projects by updating a project using an active record collection of roles.

But every once in a while we are getting an error stating **ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid -  Validation failed: Role has already been taken**.

My understanding is that Rails handles the deleting and creating of assignments automatically for us. Am I doing something wrong causing this error?

```
Class Project 

  has_many :assigned_roles, source: :role, through: :assignments 

....

  def assign_users(user_ids = :all)
    if user_ids == :all
      roles = subscription.roles
    else
      roles = subscription.roles.where(user_id: user_ids)
    end
    update!(assigned_roles: roles)
  end
```

Comment: Do you have more code for your Project, Role or User class. Particularly any validation related code like `validates :some_property, ...`

Comment: Class Assignment has "validates_uniqueness_of :role_id, scope: :project_id"

Comment: You should probably edit your code snippet to include that. That's definitely relevant to your error. You should also probably include whatever code defines "subscription" as it might be relevant, I'll explain more in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is occurring because somewhere in your code you are adding the same role to a project twice. The line `"validates_uniqueness_of :role_id, scope: :project_id"` means you can't have the same role id attached to a given project more than once.

As for where the duplicate assignment is happening, that's tricky. I don't know how `subscription.roles` gets created, but it could be that sometimes returns duplicate values. You'll have to look through your entire code base to find where that might be happening.